# Parse .csv into 3d array in C

Tags: c, csv, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a program that will permute the columns of a given CSV. My aim is to **parse the CSV into a 3D char array, transpose it, permute it, transpose back, write to out file**.

I have an issue with the function `getRows()`. Each time I increment to the next row, it seems that the **first row is being overwritten**. I have posted the whole thing since its not unlikely I've cocked up at an earlier stage and that is causing the problem (forgive me if I've done something very stupid, I am new to C)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    #define MAXLEN 10

    char*** getRows(FILE *file, char*** rows);
    char*** createArray(int size);    

    /* Fucntion to read a csv and output the rows permuted */
    int main() 
    {
        char*** rows;
        FILE *fp;

        fp = fopen("text.csv", "r");
        if(fp == NULL) 
        {
            printf("Didn't open\n");
            return -1;
        }
        rows = createArray(MAXLEN);
        rows = getRows(fp, rows);
        fclose(fp);

        return 0;
    }

/* Initializes Array */
    char*** createArray(int size)
    {
        char* values = calloc(size*size, sizeof(char));
        char** row;
        char*** rows = malloc(size*sizeof(char**));
        int i, j;
        for (i=0; i<size; ++i)
        {
            row = malloc(size*sizeof(char*));

            for(j=0; j<size; ++j)
            {
                row[j] = values + j*size;
            }

        rows[i] = row;
    }
    return rows;
}

/* Poppulates the array with the file data */
char*** getRows(FILE *file, char*** rows)
{
    int c;
    int i, j, k;

    i = j = k = 0;
    while((c=fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ');
        else if (c == ',') /*indicate end of entry and move to next entry in row*/
        {
            rows[i][j][k] = '\0'; 
            ++j;
            k = 0;
        }
        else if (c == '\n') /*indicate end of entry, indicate end of row, move to next row*/
        {
            rows[i][j][k] = '\0';
            rows[i][j+1][0] = '\0';
            ++i;
            j = k = 0;
        }
        else /* add char to entry */
        {
            rows[i][j][k] = c;

            /* Debugging */
            printf("%i\t%i\t%i\t", i, j, k);
            putchar(rows[i][j][k]);
            printf("\t");
            putchar(rows[0][0][0]);
            printf("\n");

            ++k;
        }
    }
    rows[i][j][k] = '\0';
    rows[i+1][0][0] = '\0';
    return rows;    
 }
```

So the debugging logs the following `[i, j, k, rows[i][j][k], rows[0][0][0]]`

```
0       0       0       h       h
0       0       1       e       h
0       0       2       a       h
0       0       3       d       h
0       0       4       e       h
0       0       5       r       h
0       0       6       1       h
0       1       0       h       h
0       1       1       e       h
0       1       2       a       h
0       1       3       d       h
0       1       4       e       h
0       1       5       r       h
0       1       6       2       h
0       2       0       h       h
0       2       1       e       h
0       2       2       a       h
0       2       3       d       h
0       2       4       e       h
0       2       5       r       h
0       2       6       3       h
1       0       0       1       1
1       1       0       2       1
1       2       0       3       1
2       0       0       4       4
2       1       0       5       4
2       2       0       6       4
3       0       0       7       7
3       1       0       8       7
3       2       0       9       7
```

I hope that's all clear. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Well, Phil Barber, lost interest in your problem? Found the solution? Went home? It would be polite to inform us.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the help! I never would have figured that out on my own. Sorry for leaving you hanging, I had to go out and hadn't had a chance to check back. I'm replying on my phone now so I hope you see this message, can't see a 'reply'  button anywhere! I will try this correction when I get back. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in Create.

`rows` points to an array of rows. Each row has columns and each column has a value (one value).

When you assign the address of the values to the column of the row, I see `i` is not involved. That indicates you assign the addresses of the first rows of `values` repeatedly to each `row[i][k]`.

So not only your first row is overwritten, all your rows are overwritten (there is only one row of values).

Later, in `getRows` I see you use `rows` as `rows[i][j][k]`. So each `row[i][j]` has `size` values. Then there are `size*size*size` values (you only allocate `size*size`):

```
char*** createArray(int size)
{
    char* values = calloc(size*size*size, sizeof(char));
    char** row;
    char*** rows = malloc(size*sizeof(char**));
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        row = malloc(size*sizeof(char*));

        for(j=0; j<size; ++j)
        {
            row[j] = values + i*size*size + j*size;
        }
        rows[i] = row;
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. Your solution worked!
Not had to deal with this memory allocation business before so your explanation really helped. Cheers!